# my batch script gives file name, directory names error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

when I run this script

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%userprofile%\desktop\myfile.txt") do type NUL > "%userprofile%\desktop\user\%%I.mp3"
pause
exit
```

I get this error

> the filename, directory name,or volume label syntax is incorrect

can anyone help fix the error

Comment: check the contents of `%%I`. You probably want something like `%%~nxI`. See `for /?` for help.

Comment: Without knowing the content in myfile.txt, it's hard to see what's really going on.  Can you post a sample of your myfile.txt?

Comment: Replace `type NUL >` with `echo` to see filename(s) and compare with  [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions) rules.

Answer (score 1):

Stephan and Wes both alluded to the most likely source of your problem in their comments.

Your myFile.txt most likely contains the full path to some files or folders, including the drive letter. The %USERPROFILE% also contains a full path with drive letter. Suppose the user is "someUser", and the path in the file is "c:\somePath\someFile.ext", then you end up with:

```
echo nul >"C:\Users\someUser\desktop\user\c:\somePath\someFile.ext.mp3"
```

Such an erroneous path will yield the error message you have posted. A valid path can include at most a single colon after the drive letter, but the above has two colons.

You could solve that problem by preserving just the name of the file via `%%~nI`, which would produce:

```
echo nul >"C:\Users\someUser\desktop\user\someFile.mp3"
```

I'm still concerned about the "user" folder within your desktop. That looks suspicious. If that folder does not exist, then you will get a different error message: `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: @Wes Larson the text file only contains different names on each line.. the main purpose of the the script is to create an Mp3 file with the names in the text file.